# Django manage.py - Creating auth_permission and django_content_type tables

Tags: django, django-manage.py

I am unable to use syncdb because my app uses some MySQL views.  I have run `manage.py sqlall <app>`, but this does not output the SQL for django_content_type table or the auth_permission tables.  I have also had a look into south and django evolution, but they both require syncdb, and I'm not sure they would help anyway.

I have manually added some models to the tables, but this is getting frustrating, and having installed the dbsettings app I am unsure of what I now need to enter.

Does anyone know of a way to get manage.py (or something else) to output the SQL for these tables and their contents?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the exact stacktrace?

Comment: The last line is `_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1060, "Duplicate column name 'ServerID'")` - it's something to do with some odd views in MySQL.  I've given up on trying to get syncdb working, if I start another django project from scratch I'll use south or evolution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Having done a bit more digging, I found these:
[Fixing the auth_permission table after renaming a model in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593810/fixing-the-auth-permission-table-after-renaming-a-model-in-django) and [manage.py sql command for django models - Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246363/manage-py-sql-command-for-django-models-django).

These output the tables, but not the data:

```
python manage.py sql auth
python manage.py sql admin
```

But [this](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/698/) gets a lot closer.  In the end I managed it with the following:

```
from django.contrib.auth.management import create_permissions
from django.db.models import get_apps
for app in get_apps():
    create_permissions(app, None, 2)

from django.contrib.contenttypes.management import update_all_contenttypes
update_all_contenttypes(interactive=True)
```

This adds all the permissions and then all the content types which are needed.  `interactive=True` means that it asks you if you want to remove stale content types.

Comment: What file does this belong in?

Comment: It's a while since I did this, but I think I was just using the interactive console.

Answer (score 2):

@hajamie solution works for older supported version, taking a hint, below is what worked for me!

**django = 1.9.7**

```
from django.contrib.auth.management import create_permissions
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
from django.apps import apps
def fix_user_permission():
    """
    run this method via shell whenever any amendments in any of the tables is made
    """
    print "fixing user permissions"
     # delete pre-existing user permission 
    Permission.objects.all().delete()
    apps.models_module = True
    create_permissions(apps, verbosity=0)
    apps.models_module = None
    print "process completed - fixed user permissions"
```

Comment: In Django 1.11 this throws Exception: 
`app_label = app_config.label    `  \n 
`AttributeError: 'Apps' object has no attribute 'label'`

Comment: This worked for me in Django 1.11: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40092780

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution I found is to install [Django Extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions), add it to settings.INSTALLED_APPS and run:

```
manage.py update_permissions
```